# Get phone number and email's user using Windows 10 SDK (UWP)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm developping a Windows 10 application and I would like to access some user informations. I checked the User class but neither phone number nor email seem to be available. Is it possible to retrieve them?

Comment: No, that is personally identifying information that is not accessible by design.

Comment: Allright it's understandable for security reasons...